# Какие существуют методы включения автозапуска системы?

Tags: python, bios, autoload

Какие есть варианты включения автозапуска пк по заданному времени? Возможно ли это сделать из программного кода? Что насчет python, возможно ли это сделать из сценария на нём?

Comment: А как вы себе вообще представляете запуск программного кода (или скрипта, не суть) на неработающем компьютере? Именно - выключенного, а не находящегося в спящем режиме. Просто интересно?

Comment: @passant читайте внимательнее: "включения автозапуска пк". Я спрашивал во втором вопросе, можно ли программно задать настройки автозапуска

Comment: '@user309217 читаю очень внимательно. Я знаю, что такое автозапуск программы (или точнее - процесса) и понимаю, как он может реализоваться на программном уровне. А вот что такое "автозапуск пк" -  не знаю, но трактую его как самостоятельный запуск персонального компьютера. Причем - не перевод из спящего в активное состояние, а именно включение изначально отключенного устройства. Поэтому и задал вопрос, как вы себе это представляете.  А исходя  из вашего второго вопроса - именно программно. Если у вас другая трактовка понятия "автозапуск пк" - будьте любезны ее привести.

Comment: Кстати, про "НАСТРОЙКИ автозапуска" - в вопросе ни слова.

Comment: я знаю другой вариант и его можно использовать. но, нужено иметь более одного устройства (ПК): либо настоящий сервер, который будет сам включатся и только потом слать сигнал "Wake on lan" и этот сигнал Вам надо генерировать либо... либо Вам нужно залезть в настройки Вашего маршрутизатора и включить опцию "Wake on lan". иначе выключений пк не запуститя, так как биос не может выполнять питоновкие скрипты

Comment: @user309217, перефразируйте первое предложение (исправьте вопрос), чтобы избежать недопонимания. Например так: "Какие есть варианты программно изменить настройки автозапуска пк по заданному времени?"